# How to create fixed sidenav and fixed toolbar using Angular Material

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I want to crate layout as there in http://flatlogic.github.io/angular-material-dashboard/#/dashboard

I tried with the following layout but i am not able to achieve it where the tool bar on top is fixed and we will get scroll only for the content view

[image: Layout]

How to acheive the layout as mentioned in above link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $timeout, $mdSidenav, $log) {
    $scope.toggleRight = function(){
        $mdSidenav("right").toggle();
    };
  })
```

```css
body{
   /* This is only needed because I can't add layout="column" to the BODY tag in this example. */
   display: flex;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.4/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div ng-app="BlankApp" layout="column" flex>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="ctrl" layout="row" flex>
  <md-sidenav md-is-locked-open="true" style="width: 80px;">
    <md-toolbar>
       <a class="md-toolbar-tools"><h1>AMD</h1></a>
     </md-toolbar>
     left side
  </md-sidenav>
  <div layout="column" flex>
    <md-toolbar layout="row" layout-align="end center">
      <md-button class="toolbar-button">Search</md-button>
      <md-button class="toolbar-button" ng-click="toggleRight()">Toggle Right</md-button>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-content flex layout-padding>
      <div style="height: 2000px">tall content</div>
    </md-content>
  </div>
    <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-right" md-component-id="right" style="width: 80px;">
    <md-toolbar>
       <a class="md-toolbar-tools"><h1>right</h1></a>
     </md-toolbar>
     right side
  </md-sidenav>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a CSS flexbox. This enables you to arrange the items accordingly. Use the overflow property to control the scrollbars. See here:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

I created a sample fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/q0g6gtn9/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="header">Navigation bar</div>
  <div class="content">  
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing..</p>            
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body,
.wrap {
  height: 100%; 
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 1em;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use Angular Material Design to achieve it. Is there any way to achieve it using Angular Material Library

Comment: Why that preference?